# Store an li element on a array and send it Laravel 5.2

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to store the `li` values on an array and then send it to the controller where I will save the second position on the database.. I'm new in Laravel, so I'm sorry if the question is stupid.

Some prints of the code:

[ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaOig.png)

[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHh3c.png)

Comment: [Error]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KjfnP.png
  [Routes]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QSkFa.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Please refer it  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask